# rendering html after changing code on already running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
              <div class="form-group">

               <label>{{'patient_form.Title' | translate:translationData}}</label>

                <select class="form-control" ng-model="Patient.title" >

                  <option value=""> select (Here i have inserted this "select" as placeholder but not getting on local host) </option>
                  <option value="mr">{{'title.mr' | translate:translationData}}</option>
                  <option value="mrs">{{'title.mrs' | translate:translationData}}</option>
                  <option value="ms">{{'title.ms' | translate:translationData}}</option>
                  <option value="Miss">{{'title.miss' | translate:translationData}}</option>
                  <option value="dr">{{'title.dr' | translate:translationData}}</option>
                  <option value="Master">{{'title.master' | translate:translationData}}</option>
                  <option value="RMT">{{'title.rmt' | translate:translationData}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
```

just want to place it as placeholder of dropdown but not getting while project is already running on rails server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this if you are doing this in rails view .

```
 <%=select_tag "dropdown_variable",options_from_collection_for_select(@dropdown_variable , "id", "")"%>
```

Comment: no any change in code is not processed by rails server but as a simple html its coming.its just a placeholder you can check it as a html

Comment: Can you show what is it displaying for you in browser with inspect element , maybe that will give a clearer picture .